# Regex to get the word after

Tags: regex

How can I get the following string using Regex? Example below

How can I get the string `Jama2000.00` from the following string together with the period and the following zeros

> "The name is Jama2000.00"

Or this one to return `car`

> This is a car

Or return `yesterday`

> She came to the store yesterday

Literally, return any string that comes after the phrase passed

Comment: You mean everything after the last space, or what? To all intents and purposes, something containing a period is not a word, so can you provide some conditions the search string has to adhere to?

Comment: Try matching 1+ times a non whitespace char and assert the end of the string `\S+$` If that is the case you might also split on a space and take the last entry if you are using it in code.

Comment: [The name is (.+)](https://regex101.com/r/DwUlNo/2/) → [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution to get the last part of a sting up until a whitespace character.

**Reg exp:** `.+?([^\s]+)$`

**Replace with:** `$1`

[<kbd>TEST IT HERE</kbd>](https://regex101.com/r/ZO8QOD/3)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, but what about just any string, not just Jama2000.00

Comment: [Here's a good learning resource for regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and [google search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=nqcPXZELx7iBBuvPgdgK&q=test+regex+online&oq=test+regex&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i67l3j0l2j0i67j0l4.22928.23368..27897...0.0..0.78.141.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.2PzWm1Ava4k) displays a whole host of online testers.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how our inputs might look like here, we can for instance design an expression such as:

```
^.*\s+([\w.]+)$
```

that might probably work.

```js
const regex = /^.*\s+([\w.]+)$/gm;
const str = `The name is Jama2000.00
This is a car
She came to the store yesterday
`;
const subst = `$1`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xcGXji/1/)

Comment: thanks. but it only works for the string Jama2000.00 not other types of strings passes